# Can Named Range "Comment" fields be preserved when copying to a new Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of VBA functions (UDFs) for calculating various properties of steam that exist in a standard Excel calculation, and I have recently added a LAMBDA function to all the top-level functions to aid user understanding.
For example, I have a VBA function called "psat" which is hidden from the Excel intellisense system (via Option Private Module) and a LAMBDA function "p_sat" defined as:

```
=LAMBDA(temperature_K, psat(temperature_K))
```

.i.e. my LAMBDA function calls the VBA function behind the scenes, but allows me to provide intellisense variable names (with units of measure) AND the Comment field on the Named Range definition appears in the function autocomplete list as a tooltip, so I can have something like:

```
Takes a temperature (K) and calculates the saturation pressure (bara)
```

This all works well within the template calculation. Where the fun starts is when users try to copy the tool into their wider calculations - I have a pretty robust macro button in the template that will move the VBA code module across to a user-selected target Workbook, and then copy the template calculation sheet over as well. They then automatically get the Named Ranges transferred as well, because I have copied a sheet over that refers to those LAMBDA functions.

The behaviour I am seeing, and am currently unable to work around (without great tedium) is that the "Comment" field from all Named Ranges seems to get dropped when copying over to the new Workbook. I have now tested variations including:

1. Manually copy a cell containing a reference to one of the LAMBDA functions to a new Workbook - this resolves to #NAME! because I don't copy the VBA code for the UDF that the LAMBDA is trying to call. But the Named Range does transfer APART FROM the Comment field.
2. Manually copy an entire sheet containing cells that reference various LAMBDA functions. Again, I have not moved the code module, so it doesn't fully work, but the Named Ranges all transfer APART FROM the Comment fields.
3. The automated approach, where I essentially copy the VBA module to a new Workbook and then copy the whole sheet of formulae over. This is my original intent.

I have tried searching on SO and generally online for documented 'Comment dropping' behaviour when copying Named Ranges between Workbooks, but could not find any definitive 'expected behaviour'. Does anyone know if this is a bug, or whether it is 'by design' (which in this case, IMO, would just be a known bug they can't be bothered to fix)?
(I am using Excel 365 version 2302)

Finally, if this is a repeatable issue without fix, is my best option to just programmatically reinstate the Comment fields with my macro button that moves the VBA code module and the template sheet across? i.e. backfill the missing data after the Named Ranges have been (mostly) moved.

Comment: Would it be possible going the other direction? Getting everything from the user-selected workbook into the current one and saving it as the user-selected one (after removing the robust button). Just thinking "out loud"..

Comment: "just programmatically reinstate the Comment fields" - did you try that?  Did it work?

Comment: @Notus_Panda, this would work in some circumstances, so it is a good thought, but in a large minority of cases the complexity of this would be too great (too much code to move, plus sheets).

Comment: @TimWilliams, no I have not tried this but assume it is possible. If no-one has any ideas beyond that, I will probably try it in a week or so, when I can find the time.